# IPhone UITableView selected visual when cell is a WebView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, webview

My UITableView has a custom Cell which is a webView basically.

When the user selected the webView, how can I give the user s visual feed back, like a flash of the cell etc.

Comment: by default, when tapping a cell that should happen. Maybe your webview is hidding it and you just can see it?

Comment: Exactly, is there a way to display something in the cell when selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience when I implement this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

The cell would automatically turn blue until I then deselect it.